# How to convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format to MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

How to convert getdate() function to MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS format in MSSQL.

Comment: SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FORMAT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT FORMAT ( GETDATE(), 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

**FORMAT()** function is available from SQL SERVER 2012 or Above Versions, if you want to use for older SQL SERVER Versions use this Query

```
SELECT convert(varchar,getdate(), 110) + ' ' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)
```

Use this [link](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) for reference on how to convert to other formats